# Force a form field to be populated in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using Django 1.4 with Python 2.7 and Ubunutu 12.04.

I have a form that will update a user's profile.  The last item in the form is the password.  I pre-populate the form with the existing user's data.  The password field does not get pre-populated - and that's fine.

The problem is that when I "save" the data it overwrites the password to be a null or empty field (I can't tell which).  Bad.

What can I do to prevent this?

I've tried to make it a required field (`forms.py`):

```
password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(), required = True)
```

Didn't work.

I've tried to check that the password is not `None` before updating it (`views.py`):

```
if (request.POST.get('password') is not None):
    user.set_password(request.POST.get('password'))
```

Didn't work.

Does an empty form value come back as `None`?  If not, what does it come back as and how can I check if it's empty?

EDIT 1:
I updated my one of my `views` to check for validation - maybe I did this wrong?

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    """
    ..  function:: profile()

        Provide the profile page, where it can be updated

        :param request: Django Request object
    """
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)
        user_dict = createUserProfileDict(user)
        form = ProfileForm(initial = user_dict);
        data = { 'user' : request.user }
        data.update({ 'form' : form })
        data.update(csrf(request))

        if form.is_valid():
            return render_to_response("profile.html", data)
```

Now I receive the following error:

```
The view rsb.views.profile didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

So, it appears my form is not valid?  How can I find out why?

Here is the `update_profile view`:

```
@login_required
def update_profile(request):
    """
    ..  function:: profile()

        provide the profile page

        :param request: Django Request object
    """
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = User.objects.get(username = request.user)
        user.first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        user.email = request.POST.get('email')
        if (request.POST.get('password') is not None):
            user.set_password(request.POST.get('password'))
        user.save()

        # Update the additional user information tied to the user
        user_info = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id = user.id)
        user_info.company_name = request.POST.get('company_name')
        user_info.client_type = request.POST.get('client_type')
        user_info.address1 = request.POST.get('address1')
        user_info.address2 = request.POST.get('address2')
        user_info.city = request.POST.get('city')
        user_info.state = request.POST.get('state')
        user_info.country = request.POST.get('country')
        user_info.zip_code = request.POST.get('zip_code')
        user_info.phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
        user_info.save()

    return profile(request)
```

Comment: Have you checked submitted form is valid?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this.  `if (request.POST.get('password').is_valid())`?  I read the Django docs about this, but as always, they have no actual examples.  :(

Comment: is_valid refers to the full form object, not a single field

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo And where/how would I do this check?

Comment: post your profile function, seems to be that one generating the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remember to control if your form "is_valid()"

To theck if your form has been submitted with empty values or not, use

```
MyForm.has_changed()
```

too bad this is not a documented functionality :(

If you want a default password, i suggest you check if the field is valid then use something like

```
''.join([choice(string.letters + string.digits) for i in range(7)])
```

to generate a new password for the user (range(7) is the length you want). Then use an opt-in method (see: send a user an email with his temporary password)

edit based on new context:

from the django docs:

```
If a Field has required=False and you pass clean() an empty value, 
then clean() will return a normalized empty value 
rather than raising ValidationError.     
For CharField, this will be a Unicode empty string. 
For other Field classes, it might be None. (This varies from field to field.)
```

That's it, your password field should have required=False, so you can treat that as an empty string

Then in your view you could do:

```
if input_password != '' and input_password != saved_password:
    saved_password = input_password
```

It's just pseudocode, but it should give you a clear idea

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on where `MyForm.has_changed()` would go?  In the `view`?  I'm not trying to generate a password - I just want it so that if they don't type anything in as the password then it does not update the password.

Comment: Yes, you should process those things inside your pview (after you posted the form). I see your problem now, didn't understand. I'll edit my answer then. You just have to check the new password against the old one. In case they don't match and the field is either not None or not empty, update :)

Comment: I see...kinda counter-intuitive, imo, but I understand.  Thank you.

Comment: "If the input password is not empty and the input password is different from the saved one, update the saved one. Otherwise, do nothing" how's this counter intuitive? You just have to adapt it to your update password function. Btw, did you manage to solve your problem? Post also your profile function, since that seems to be the problem (or if you solved it anyway, gg!)

Comment: The functionality behind how to check and change the password is very straight-forward.  The way Django handles `required = True` and not passing an `empty string` when the field is left empty was what I found counter-intuitive.  I successfully implemented my functionality, thanks.  :)

Comment: nice to know :) about the required True/False, it's mostly used to validate the form, not the field itself. In fact, if required=True and you don't provide a field, an error is raised from is_valid() method, because django handles this before anything else. You need a "special" kind of validation yourself, so you set required=False if you want to skip django's check and do a validation yourself.